# Using assertion in main() method

Tags: java, assertions

Here is a question I'm trying to answer:

> **Which of the following use assertions appropriately?**
>
> ```
> public class Hunt {
>   public static void main(String... args) {
>       int y = 10;
>       assert y > 5; // #1
>       new Hunt().netant(y);
>   }
>
>   public void netant(int x) {
>       assert x > 0; // #2
>       anteater(x);
>   }
>
>   private void anteater(int x) {
>       assert x > 0; // #3
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Choose: 2
>
> **Options**:
>
> 1. #1
> 2. #2
> 3. #3
> 4. The program has runtime errors although assertions are used correctly
>
> **Correct Answer**: 1 & 3
>
> **Explanation**: It is not advisable to use assertions to assert arguments of public methods
>
> *Source:http://www.certpal.com*

The answer states "*It is not advisable to use assertions to assert arguments of public methods*". But in the above code even though assert statement is used to assert arguments of main() method it is chosen as the right answer!

Is it advisable to use assert statement in main() method?

Comment: no.... assert should only be used in testclasses

Comment: So option 1 is correct?

Comment: The assert statement isn't being used to assert an argument of `main()`, it's being used on a field inside `main()`, although as @PhilippSander you'd only use assert during testing - you wouldn't rely on it to check data normally.

Comment: None of them is correct. In the first case it is entirely pointless, as it merely asserts something the code has just accomplished. In the other cases it should be a proper runtime check, not something that would just give the user a fright.

Answer (score 3):

Assertions are a defence mechanism for coding errors. Entering an invalid argument in to a public method is a user error, even if it's an API a programmer is using.

Users should never see an assert, tests should.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advisable to use assertions to assert **arguments** of public methods. `y` is not an argument.

```
 public static void main(String... args) {
        int y = 10;
        assert y > 5; // #1
        new Hunt().netant(y);
 }
```

However, the following is not a good practice:

```
 public static void main(String... args) {
    assert args.length==42;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) should not be used to:

- Argument checking in public methods
- To do any work that your application requires for correct operation

---

- `#1`: Check a value of a local variable. Checking the arguments of the main method with assertions is not a correct use but checking a local variable is valid.
- `#2`: Check the parameter of a public method. Invalid use of assertions.
- `#3`: Check the parameter of a private method. The class controls the
  parameters used in the method invocation, so this is a valid use.